# if statement in a template not working

Tags: craft3, entries, categories

I am making a condition to use a certain template for a specific article category, but it's not working and giving me an error.

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% set title = category.title %}

{% block head %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


    {% if category.postType=="video" or category.videoLink|length%}
        {% include 'news/hiwar.html' %}
    {% elseif category.postType=="file" %}
        {% include 'news/file.html' %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'news/articless.html' %}
    {% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you add the error you are getting to your question?

Comment: What does this {{ category.postType }} or this {{ category.videoLink|length }} show for a value?

Answer (score -1):

5th line: `category.videoLink|length%}`
Could you try to insert a space between "length" and "%"?